# How to revoke alter privilege from postgres?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

My Postgres DB has a user - "myuser" who has access to everycommand in schema `my_schema`.

I want to restrict the user to use only basic sequelize commands like Create, Update, Delete, Select. But the user should not be able to Alter the table (in sequelize, he shouldn't be able to do .sync{} operation).

I have already tried doing:

```
REVOKE ALTER ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA my_schema from myuser
```

But the above command is giving error!

**Commands I have used to create role is:**

```
CREATE ROLE app_readwrite1;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE dvdrental TO app_readwrite1;
GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA app_schema TO app_readwrite1;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA app_schema TO app_readwrite1;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA app_schema GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO app_readwrite1;
GRANT USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA app_schema TO app_readwrite1;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA app_schema GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCES TO app_readwrite1;
```

After creating role above, I am creating user and assigning him the role.

Still, I can use Model.sync()- basically "ALTER" command along with CRUD operations.

How can I restrict the user from using alter command?

Comment: The user "postgres" is normally the default superuser. A superuser can always do everything in a database, REVOKE won't change that. Only your DBA should be able to use this role, nobody or nothing else. Never. Ever.

Comment: How to do it if I create another user? Can you please share the command?

Comment: Check the examples in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-revoke.html

Comment: Couldn't understand the docs that's why asked Question here @FrankHeikens

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? A normal user (not a superuser) can never alter a table (or any other object) that he doesn't own.

Comment: to be honest, it looks like you try to solve a problem that should not exist: You never ever use a superuser for random users and you never use the owner of an object for production either

Comment: I would suggest reading [Roles](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/user-manag.html). At some point you are going to need to know that information, might as well be now.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks I will have a look into Roles. Basically I have created a new user now and now just want to revoke the "Alter" access. After creating and granting CRUD access to my schema tables, he magically got the ALTER permission :(

Comment: You are doing this backwards, you need to read the docs first then come up with specific questions. For instance from [Grant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html): 'The right to drop an object, or to alter its definition in any way, is not treated as a grantable privilege; it is inherent in the owner, and cannot be granted or revoked. '

Comment: Hi @AdrianKlaver, I covered the docs. Today, I have created another role and gave crud operations access to it. Now still it's having alter, drop privilege. By any means can I revoke those privilege? If this is something which can't be revoked then is there any alternative for this?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have read about roles and have create roles with CRUD operation and create a new user and assigned the role to that user. Is there by any means I can revoke the alter, drop privilege? It should be possible doing this right ?

Comment: It sounds as if that user also created those tables and thus is the owner. The owner of a table always has full privileges. You need to give those "crud privileges" to a user/role that is not the owner - they don't have the ALTER privilege anyway so there is no need to revoke them to begin with.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hi! Yes correct, I am creating the tables with that user- sorry I didn't knew this part. So now the solution is to create table with some other user and after that change the user to the one with CRUD so that table modification queries can't be executed? Is this correct? Or is there any better option?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Even when tables are created by superuser, my other user which I created by giving CRUD privilege is still able to use alter command :(

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong: https://i.imgur.com/frQKRMv.png

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have included the command I have used to create the role (in the question) and later I have just assigned it to a user. - All of these cmd I have run as an superuser: "postgres". I can't understand why it's not happening :( The creation of tables is done by Model.sync({alter: true}) and later once tables are created, I am changing the postgres user back to the new user which shouldn't have the alter privilege but it still have :(

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I guess I maybe doing something wrong while creating the role itself. I have included the command I am using to create role in the question above. I will be obliged if you can have a look.

Comment: I have no idea "Model.sync" is or does - but maybe that code connects as `app_readwrite1` and thus the tables are created by that user making `app_readwrite1` the owner of the tables (with all privileges)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Model.sync() is just "Alter" sql command. I am creating the table with user - postgres and later using my own user( having CRUD access) but still it's successfully performing alter :(